# Difference between event.target and getelementbyid

Tags: javascript

I am working with the `File API` and I was wondering if there's a difference between `event.target.files[0]` and `getElementbyId("demo").files[0]`

The latter seems to work. Context may help, the code below uses the instance of `event.target.files[0]`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Home Page </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
        <output id="list"></output>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
          function handleFileSelect(evt) { 
            // grab the file that was uploaded which is type File. 
            // evt is the event that was triggered
            // evt.target returns the element that triggered the event 
            // evt.target.files[0] returns the file that was uploaded, type File
            var file = evt.target.files[0]; 

            //file is not of TYPE BLOB!!!

            // instantiate a FileReader object to read/save the file that was uploaded
            var reader = new FileReader();

            // read the file and save as an array 
            arrayoffile=reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arrayoffile.length;
            window.alert("hello");

          }

          document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: if it works, there's no difference: JS provides lots of ways to reach interesting elements.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I attached an example that shows the former function not working.

Comment: @dandavis the former does not work

Comment: I doubt the later works. `p` elements don't have a `files` property. Did you mean `getElementbyId("file").files[0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `evt.target.files[0]` and `document.getElementById('file').files[0]` are the very same objects in the `handleFileSelect` handler.

The problem is that you're using [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) incorrectly. The [`readAsArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) only starts reading the buffer.

> The readAsArrayBuffer method is used to start reading the contents of
>   a specified Blob or File. When the read operation is finished, the
>   readyState becomes DONE, and the loadend is triggered. At that time,
>   the result attribute contains an ArrayBuffer representing the file's
>   data.

You need to attach event handlers `onload` and/or `onerror` to get some results. Take a look below:

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var file = evt.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    var arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arrayBuffer.byteLength;
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
<output id="list"></output>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Note that [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) offers [`byteLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/byteLength) property.

Comment: would it be possible to print the file that is now saved as arrayBuffer?

Comment: @Crt generally speaking yes but it depends on the content i.e. [an image](https://jsfiddle.net/Jan_Miksovsky/yy7Zs/).

Comment: Could you corroborate my thinking about what is going on in the code. Once the file has been selected by the user, the handleFileSelect function is called and the event that is passed is the 'change' event. The **file** variable contains the file that was selected. Then, readAsArrayBuffer is called on that file and once it finishes reading, the reader.onload function is called and is passed the load event because that is what triggered it.

Comment: @Crt Yes, that's exactly what happens.

Answer (score 2):

`readAsArrayBuffer` does not return a value, you need to listen to the event of the Reader.

[MDN FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer)

> When the read operation is finished, the `readyState` becomes `DONE`, and the `loadend` is triggered. At that time, the `result` attribute contains an ArrayBuffer representing the file's data.

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function(e) {
   var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
}

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

And the size of an ArrayBuffer is not `length` but [`byteLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/byteLength).